# CSS: Wrapping Divs

Tags: css, box-sizing

I have a CSS menu using the `checkbox:checked` trick [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css-off-screen-navigation-menu/)

But my issue is that when the menu is open, the content overflows off the side of the parent `div` - How do I make the `div`s fluid so that that wrap around to the next row and push each other along?

I have looked at [Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), I have never used them before, but feel this could be the right track.

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tcyerLn/) that illustrates what I am trying to do.

Thank you :)

**EDIT**

I've done some experimenting and it is the magic combination of padding and box-sizing - I've also just stumbled upon this useful post => [International box-sizing Awareness Day](https://css-tricks.com/international-box-sizing-awareness-day/)

**EDIT**

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<input type="checkbox" />
  <div id="container">
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
    <div class="item">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
  width: 500px;
  background: blue;
}
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #container {
    transition: left 1s;
    left: 250px;
    }

#container {
  position: relative;
  transition: left 1s;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

Comment: I think you have to use margin instead of `left` https://jsfiddle.net/6tcyerLn/2/

Comment: As well as the padding-left:250px rather than "left", you do not need the width on id container either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are moving the `left` value of **offset menu**, which moves the menu item to left `250px`. Similar thing will occur if you use `margin-left` property, because of `width:100%`.

instead, if you increase the padding, which will cause the increment inwards and reduce width of parent container, causing the `item` elements to fall on next life if no space is found.

Check the below snippet, where i am changing the padding value

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#content {
  width: 500px;
  background: blue;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #container {
  transition: padding 1s;
  padding-left: 250px;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  transition: padding 1s;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <input type="checkbox" />

  <div id="container">

    <div class="item">
      Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Hello
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Deepak_Yadav Fantastic that's the answer! CSS is wondeful

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're moving the whole container so everything inside it moves too.

What you actually want to do is move the first `.item`.

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #container .item:first-child {
  transition: margin-left 1s;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
```

```css
#content {
  width: 500px;
  background: blue;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #container .item:first-child {
  transition: margin-left 1s;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <input type="checkbox" />

  <div id="container">

    <div class="item">
      Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Hello
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really great, thanks - But I want the divs to line up, I want the three divs that wrap to the start of the container (0px) to wrap to the first element (250px)

Comment: Then perhaps the other answer is for you.

Answer (score 0):

As per your JSFiddle example you have to change few properties :

HTML : one line has to added for clear the floating

```
<div id="content">

<input type="checkbox" />

  <div id="container">

    <div class="item">
    Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item">
Hello
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS would be :

```
#content {
  width: 500px;
  background: blue;
}
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #container {
    transition: margin-left 1s;
    margin-left: 250px;
    }

#container {
  position: relative;
  transition: margin-left 1s;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 4px;
}
```